# TransactionScope and Azure Table Storage

Tags: azure, transactions, scope, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

Is there an equivalent to TransactionScope that you can use with Azure Table Storage?

what I'm trying to do is the following:

```cs
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope) {
    account.balance -= 10;
    purchaseOrders.Add(order);
    accountDataSource.SaveChanges();
    purchaseOrdersDataSource.SaveChanges();
    scope.Complete();
}
```

If for some reason saving the account works, but saving the purchase order fails, I don't want the account to decrement the balance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within a single table and single partition, you may write multiple rows in an entity group transaction. There's no built-in transaction mechanism when crossing partitions or tables.

that said: remember that tables are schema-less, so if you really needed a transaction, you could store both your account row and your purchase order row in the same table, same partition, and do a single (transactional) save.

Comment: So there is no way of insuring integrity in the data when it comes down to Azure Tables?
Sounds like there is a bit to desire still from this.
Thanks for the answer

Comment: No, that's not what David said. What he said is that there's no way to do transactions *cross-table or cross-partition*. If you need to perform transactions across multiple entities, you need to ensure they're in the same partition of the same table.